# Date and Time formatting using Formatter class in java

Tags: java, java-time, formatter, localdate

I'm stuck in a problem, I know that we can use `SimpleDateFormat` class or other format classes in java to format the date/time. But I'm trying to format the time and date using `Formatter` class method `format`. Is that possible? If yes, then how it is possible?

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
formatter.format("%tm/%td/%ty", date);
System.out.println(formatter);
```

I got `java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%td'`.

Comment: When asking about a problem always quote *expected output* and specify *how observed result differs*.

Answer (score 2):

You have got three (3) format specifiers (`%tm`, `%td` and `%ty`), so `format()`  immediately expects three arguments in addition to the format string. You gave only one.

The solution is *not* to repeat the same argument. There are two ways to tell `format()` to use the same argument again.

One way, give explicit argument index, from 1:

```
formatter.format("%1$tm/%1$td/%1$ty", date);
```

Output:

> 09/10/21

Other way, a `<` tells `format()` to use the same argument one more time:

```
formatter.format("%tm/%<td/%<ty", date);
```

Output is the same.